# Notation of Rational Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I was wondering what elements of the field $Q[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$ look like?

I think that $Q[\sqrt2 + \sqrt3]$ are elements of the form a + b ($\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$), where a and b are in Q.

Are elements of the field $Q[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$ of the form a+b$\sqrt 2$ + c$\sqrt 3$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try multiplying two arbitrary elements of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ with each other.  Do you notice a new term appear you didn't have before?

You may do similarly with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ to see that the proposed basis $\{1,\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\}$ does not work.  Think about the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and what relationship this has with the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Comment: Oh! I also get $\sqrt2 * \sqrt3$.

Comment: Hayden, is it true that $Q[\sqrt2 + \sqrt3]$ = $Q[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]$ then?

Comment: Precisely, you get $\sqrt{6}$.  And yes, it is.  Do you see why? (Hint: you should see pretty easily that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, so now compare their degrees over $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: I see that $Q[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$ contains $Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3]$, and I've also noted that $\sqrt 2$ - $\sqrt 3$ is in $Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3]$, and in class my notes say that this means $Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3]$ contains $Q[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$. I'm not sure I see this? What do you mean by compare their degrees?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it now! Thanks for your help Hayden. :)

Comment: Well, just in case: you know that $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ (because $1/(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$), so $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}))=\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, and likewise $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$.  This means that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, so they must be equal.

Comment: As far as "degrees" are concerned, the degree of an extension $L/K$ or ($K\subset L$, depending on the author) is defined to be the dimension of $L$ as a $K$-vector space, and we denote it by $[L:K]$.For example, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$, as you showed above, and $[\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q}]=2^{\aleph_0}$ (or just $\infty$ if you prefer).The degree of an extension has many nice properties: given $M/L/K$ a tower of extensions, $[M:K]=[M:L][L:K]$, and given $L/K$ and $\alpha\in L$ algebraic, $[K(\alpha):K]$ is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

Comment: So applying to our situation, we can check that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ had degree $4$, and hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]/[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4/4=1$, and so we conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I did a similar thing. Really appreciate your help Hayden.